# Solving $5400 \cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) - 735.75 \sin (\theta) - 600 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

$$5400 \cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) - 735.75 \sin (\theta) - 600 = 0$$

This is a static course. I understand the question. I already solved to this point, but in the book they go from here to final answer $\theta =14.5$ and $\theta = 82.5$.

Comment: The values $\theta=14.5^\circ$ and $\theta=82.5^\circ$ do not satisfy the equation given. What's the original problem?

Comment: I can't share a picture here, but it has the same logic as the 3rd problem in this PDF https://faculty.uca.edu/njaustin/ENGR2311/Archive/exam02F15.pdf

Comment: You should ask on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com), as your mistake is not likely to be with the mathematics, but with the physics.

Comment: Since it's a statics (physics) problem, I think it's perfectly reasonable to use numerical methods in finding the roots of such equations. In the example solution, it is mentioned that Wolfram Alpha was used to find approximate solutions. So you can just graph the function and numerically look for the solutions. Or, ask Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Try [Weiesstrauss substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution).

Answer (score 0):

We want to solve for $\theta$ in the equation
$$
a \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) = b \sin(\theta) + c 
$$
for some constants $a,b,c$. Squaring both sides we get
\begin{align*}
&a^2 \underbrace{\cos^2(\theta)}_{\color{blue}{1-\sin^2(\theta)}} \sin^2(\theta) = b^2 \sin^2(\theta) + 2bc \sin(\theta) + c^2\\
\implies& a^2 \sin^4(\theta)+ \left(b^2-a^2 \right) \sin^2(\theta) + 2bc \sin(\theta) +c^2 = 0
\end{align*}
Notice here that if we rename $\sin(\theta)$ as $x$, we see that the problem reduces to finding the roots of the polynomial
$$
\left(a^2\right) x^4+ \left(b^2-a^2 \right) x^2 + \left(2bc \right)x+c^2  \tag{1}
$$
which, although not impossible to solve analytically (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#The_general_case,_along_Ferrari%27s_lines) for information about the quartic formula), it's most definitely not advisable to do. If you really want to go this route, you can verify your steps by plugging the polynomial into WolframAlpha to get the [explicit roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2+x%5E4+%2B+%28b%5E2+-+a%5E2%29+x%5E2+%2B+%282+b+c%29+x+%2B+c%5E2+%3D%3D+0). Once you get these values, you simply need to take the $\arcsin$ function of the roots to get your angle, remembering that our substitution was $\sin(\theta) = x \implies \theta = \arcsin(x)$ (keeping in mind the interval on which you're working on).

For your case, if we plug $a = 5400$, $b= 735.75$ and $c=600$ into $(1)$ and [solve for the roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5400%5E2+x%5E4+%2B+%28735.75%5E2+-+5400%5E2%29+x%5E2+%2B+2%C3%97735.75%C3%97600+x+%2B+600%5E2+%3D+0), considering that since the question came from physics you're probably taking $\theta \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, we get that the positive roots of the polynomial are
\begin{align*}
x_1 &\approx 0.129913\\
x_2 &\approx 0.967978
\end{align*}
and taking the inverse sine of these values we get that the values of the angles are
\begin{align*}
\theta_1 &\approx 7.4645 \ ^\circ\\
\theta_2 &\approx 75.461\ ^\circ
\end{align*}
which you can easily verify by plugging these values into your original equation.

---

As a final note, it's clear that this method is highly inefficient since we still end up relying on an answer given by WolframAlpha to solve our original equation. Given that your PDF also uses WA to get the solutions by directly plugging the original equation into WA, I believe the intended method for the solution of this problem is to imitate this, which would give you [the same results](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5400+cos%28%CE%B8%29+sin%28%CE%B8%29+%2B+sin%28%CE%B8%29%C3%97%28-735.75%29+-+600+%3D+0) that we've previously calculated.